# Changing the application icon text dynamically in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am developing a calendar app, wherein i will using a service to display date in the application icon text itself. For Eg: If date is: 26 Apr 2010, then my application name in the phone menu will also show the same.
So I am not understanding how to change the application's icon text dynamically through program.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a way to change the Application Title in code.  I believe it's fixed once your app is installed.

If you want an icon that changes to notify the use of things [add an App Widget to your application](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) and users can add this to their Home Screen.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it were possible somehow, then most home screen/launcher applications cache the icons, so your icon would only be updated when the user restarts the phone.

As suggested in the previous post, [widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) are what you should be looking at.