# Changing the Application Icon and Alert user

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

ı am trying to make a simple app which parses XML feed of an blog and compare it with the previous post's info that already saved in the database.if they are not same this means new post is released and whenever new post is released ı want my application warn the user and change my apps icon  like in facebook app. or facebook messenger app.(puting a red alert with a number of new posts to the right bottom of the icon).   ı can compare parsed info and database info but ı dont know how to alert user and change icon. Is it possible with using AppWidgetProvider or is there any other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to change the icon of the app. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042212/android-application-icon-change) .
Maybe a possible solution is to display a proper notification to the user.